# Only first dynamically generated select box is created

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following code in my view:

```
<% @games.each_with_index do |game, i| %>
  <div class="game_<%= i %> game_hide hide" >
    <% options = options_from_collection_for_select(Player.where("game_id = ?", game.id), 'id', 'handle' ) %>
    <%= f.select(:player_ids, options, {:include_blank => true}, {id: "game_#{i}", :multiple => true} ) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Which generates the following html:

```
<div class="add-players">
  <div class="game_0 game_hide hide" >
  <input name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    <select id="game_0" multiple="multiple" name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]"><option value=""></option>
      <option value="2551">Näryt</option>
      <option value="2552">BrTT</option>
      <option value="2553">Danagorn</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="game_1 game_hide hide" >
    <input name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    <select id="game_1" multiple="multiple" name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]"><option value=""></option>
      <option value="4885">Zium</option>
      <option value="4886">Abver</option>
      <option value="4887">Xenocider</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="game_2 game_hide hide" >
    <input name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]" type="hidden" value="" />
    <select id="game_2" multiple="multiple" name="team[team_divisions_attributes][0][player_ids][]"><option value=""></option>
      <option value="4865">Odin</option>
      <option value="4866">Nazgul</option>
      <option value="4867">Dragon</option>
      ...
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

and is placed with the following jQuery:

```
//when box is checked...
$('.show-tabs .show-tab').live('click', function(){
  var tab = $('.tabs .tab:nth-of-type(' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) + ')');
  var content = $('.tab-content:nth-of-type(' + ( $(this).index() + 1 ) + ')');
  var destroy_field = content.find('input#team_team_divisions_attributes_' + $(this).index() +'__destroy');
  if ($(this).find('.checkbox').hasClass('checkBoxed')){
    //make it visible
    destroy_field.val('0');
    //shows the game div for the selected game
    $(".game-"+ $(this).index()).show();
    //what's the index?
    alert($(this).index());
    //show the associated tab
    tab.show();
    tab.click();
  } else {
    destroy_field.val('1');
    tab.hide();
    if (tab.hasClass('selected')) {
      $('.tabs .tab:visible').first().click();
      content.hide();
    }
  }
} );
```

Everything is "there" - in that I can find it on the page with developer tools in Chrome, but the select box is only being displayed for the first game (`game_0`) - Because of this, I think there's some sort of issue with the `id`'s but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: The problem is with `index()` method. `$(this).index()` will always return 0. If you could tell me what is the event you're adding this code to, then I can help you with code level. :)

Comment: I'll update my post, but what you said isn't true ;)  `alert($(this).index());` returns `0`, `1` or `2` depending on which box I check

Comment: can you please try `$('.show-tabs .show-tab').index($(this))` instead.

Comment: `$(".game-"+ $('.show-tabs .show-tab').index($(this))).show();` in place of `$(".game-"+ $(this).index()).show();`. Note that there `-` in `$(".game-"`. while you have `_` (underscores) in code.

Comment: ah right, i added the `-`'s in my code after reading Sandeep Nayak's answer, but didn't change them in the question, my bad.  let me try this out!

Comment: @ManojMonga, that worked but caused another issue - anyway, if you make an answer i'll check it and then make another question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the usage of `.index()` method. If the method is called without any argument then it will return an integer i.e. the position of the element based on the siblings. So somehow in this case `$(this).index()` is returning 0. So, I'd suggested to use different variant of the same method

Replace this line

```
$(".game-"+ $(this).index()).show();
```

with

```
$(".game-"+ $('.show-tabs .show-tab').index($(this))).show();
```

Now, it will return the index or position of the current element based upon the all the elements matched with `$('.show-tabs .show-tab')` selector.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because of using underscores (_) in the id and class. This is what I found. Might be of some use.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Underscores_in_class_and_ID_Names

Comment: interesting, didn't know the history of that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you have a mistake in the jQUERY. You hide `div` but you're trying to show `select` elements. Change it to :

```
//if this thing happens
//hides all game divs
$(".game-hide").hide();
//shows the game div for the selected game with good index method
$(".game-"+ $('.show-tabs .show-tab').index($(this))).parent('.game-hide').show();
```

explanation :

The `$(this)` is related to the `$('.show-tabs .show-tab').live('click'`. It's the current tab you have clicked. So to retrieve the index of `$(this)` you have to compare with all `$('.show-tabs .show-tab')` elements. More explanation [here](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Comment: I think you're right about the `.game_hide` div not working properly, but that didn't work.  Thanks for your answer

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how `.index()` works. (not correct because I don't know about what `$(this)` is!

Comment: sorry...likely i'm just being daft, but what should `all_this_elements_selector` be?  the parent of `game-hide`/`game-x`?  i tried that (it's `add-player`) and got nothing

Comment: In your case, it will be `$('.show-tabs .show-tab')`. See my post, I've changed it!

Comment: that didn't do it. i appreciate your help though, would give you another +1 if i could

Comment: Sorry, I revers the order... Use `$('.show-tabs .show-tab').index($(this))` for index.
And replace `_` by `-`